# Solve $u''(x) = x^{2\alpha}u(x)$ around $x=0$ with $\alpha \geq 2$ an integer, $u(0) = 1, u'(0) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Where can I find a reference to help me solve, have estimations, or the form of the solution of, the equation

$$u''(x) = x^{2\alpha}u(x)$$

around $x=0$, with $\alpha \geq 2$ an integer, $u(0) = 1, u'(0) = 0$?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Generally for problems like this, the series approach is used. I would reference any standard text in differential equations for the technique. Series then give you a very easy way to approximate the solutions as well with known regions of convergence and error terms.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I already tried but couldn't get anything...

Answer (score 2):

According to Maple, the general solution of your differential equation can be written using modified Bessel functions

$$ u \! \left(x \right) = 
c_{1} \sqrt{x}\, I_{\frac{1}{2 \alpha +2}}\! \left(\frac{x^{\alpha +1}}{\alpha +1}\right)+c_{2} \sqrt{x}\, K_{\frac{1}{2 \alpha +2}}\! \left(\frac{x^{\alpha +1}}{\alpha +1}\right)
$$

Hmm, it looks to me like the solution you want is
$$ u(x) = \Gamma\left(\frac{2\alpha+1}{2\alpha+2}\right) (2\alpha+2)^{-1/(2\alpha+2)}
\sqrt{x}\;  I_{-1/(2\alpha+2)}\left(\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}\right) $$